# appending multiple dictionaries to a list and dumping into json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm appending multiple dictionaries to a list and then converting the same to json. Its giving me multiple lists with each list adding one extra result. I want to display entire output in a single array of list.

```
mail_output = []

for i in mail_ids.split():
    result, msg_data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

    for each_response in msg_data:
        if isinstance(each_response, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(each_response[1])                  
            items_list = msg.items()
            dict_items = OrderedDict(items_list)       
            email_body = ''
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for part in msg.walk():
                    case...
            dict_items.update({'Body': email_body})
    mail_output.append(dict_items)

    print(json.dumps(mail_output, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The output I'm getting:

```
[
 {
  "Body": "Forwarded.\r\n\r\nFrom: User
  "Subject": "Fw: Tuesday", 
  "To": "<reciever@gmail.com>"
 }
]
[
 {
  "Body": "Forwarded.\r\n\r\nFrom: User
  "Subject": "Fw: Tuesday", 
  "To": "<reciever@gmail.com>"
 },
 {
  "Body": "Urgent Message.\r\n\r\nFrom: Alerts
  "Subject": "Alerts", 
  "To": "<reciever@gmail.com>"
 }
]
```

Output expected:

```
[
 {
  "Body": "Forwarded.\r\n\r\nFrom: User
  "Subject": "Fw: Tuesday", 
  "To": "<reciever@gmail.com>"
 },
 {
  "Body": "Urgent Message.\r\n\r\nFrom: Alerts
  "Subject": "Alerts", 
  "To": "<reciever@gmail.com>"
 }
 .....
]
```

Comment: the reason for that is your using `print` inside the for loop.  Move it outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mail_output = []

for i in mail_ids.split():
    result, msg_data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

    for each_response in msg_data:
        if isinstance(each_response, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(each_response[1])                  
            items_list = msg.items()
            dict_items = OrderedDict(items_list)       
            email_body = ''
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for part in msg.walk():
                    case...
            dict_items.update({'Body': email_body})
    mail_output.append(dict_items)

print(json.dumps(mail_output, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

You just have an issue with indentation.. see the last line here.. it's the only part I changed. Otherwise the script will print for each iteration of `for i in mail_ids.split()`.

Comment: Thank you. As you said its indentation problem.